# iOS: Date Components to ignore the year

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, localization, notifications

I wrote an app lets the user enter in a date on a date picker, and they will press a button to schedule a local notification 3 days before the date is approaching. The only issue is, how would I edit this code to not factor in the year that the user types in? Because they may type in something like 1980 for the year, which obviously has already passed.

I tried deleting `[dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];`, but that causes the notification to fire immediately. I also tried deleting both that and NSYearCalendarUnit from the date components, but the same thing happens. Any help is much appreciated! Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)scheduleNotifButton:(id)sender {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

    NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit )
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit )
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];

    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
    [dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
    [dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
    [dateComps setHour:13];
    [dateComps setMinute:30];
    [dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
    NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    localNotif.alertBody = @"Event is in 3 days!";
    localNotif.alertAction = nil;

    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];

}
```

Comment: What if you just ignore the year entered and substitute it with the current year?

Comment: Thank you! Could you write that in an answer so that I can mark it correct and throw some point your way? Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested:

What if you just ignore the year entered and substitute it with the current year?

Answer (score 0):

you can just get the current year, and set it to your dateComps

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[dateComps setYear:[components year]];
```

EDIT:

```
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
[dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[dateComps setYear:[components year]];

[dateComps setHour:13];
[dateComps setMinute:30];
[dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
```

Comment: Awesome thank you, so should I just replace the nscalendar in my current code to the nscalendar in the code above, and then add in the nsdatecomponent in the code above? Sorry in still very new at this.

Comment: see my edit, it should be something similar, but you can probably optimize it further